# Encrypt custom config section in ASP.NET using aspnet_regiis

Tags: asp.net, encryption, configuration, aspnet-regiis.exe

We are using a custom config section (via the NameValueConfigSection) to contain our settings.
These settings are externalised from web.config via configSource.

So, entries in web.config look something like this:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="customSettings" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
  </configSections>

  <customSettings configSource="config\customSettings.config" />
```

We want to encrypt this "customSettings.config" file on our production server, so run this command, as recommended by Microsoft (here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx)

```
aspnet_regiis -pe customSettings -site 4 -app /
```

And this produces the following output:

```
Encrypting configuration section...
Succeeded!
```

**However, it does not succeed at all, leaving the file exactly as it was**

(incidentally, this command *does work* if encrypting a non-custom section, such as an externalised connectionStrings section)

I have been able to write a little console app that does work ok, but we really want to use the standard tools to do what should be a standard operation - can anyone tell me if this is a limitation or where I am going wrong?

Thanks :)

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. If I put the customSettings in the web.config they encrypt, but if I use the configSource and have them in a separate file the aspnet_regiis says the encryption succeeds but the nodes in the file aren't encrypted. I also encrypt the connectionStrings in a different file which is in the same directory and it works fine so I know it isn't a path issue. If anyone has found the answer to this please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

I'm comparing your code with [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998372.aspx):

To encrypt the `connectionStrings` section with the DPAPI provider with the machine key store (the default configuration), run this command from a command prompt:

```
aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/MachineDPAPI" -prov "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider"
```

where:

`-pe` specifies the configuration section to encrypt.

`-app` specifies the web app's virtual path. If the app is nested, specify the nested path from the root directory, for example "`/test/aspnet/MachineDPAPI`"

`-prov` specifies the provider name.

I wonder if you need to provide the app name? And/or the provider?

And their version encloses the attribute values in quotes.

Comment: I am providing the app name "/" = root (in your case you have a named app off the root). And no, no need for Prov, as in the docs: "If you do not specify a provider using the -prov option, the provider configured as the defaultProvider is used."